# Should the top navigation be frozen (optional)?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, top-bar, navigation

In Excel, the window can be frozen in place in such a way that you can always see the name of the column even though you go way down below the 'fold' of the screen.

On SE, when you scroll, the whole page goes up (or down). This means the top navigation bar is scrolled off screen. I'm not sure if it would be a good idea or not to fix the top navigation to the top of the screen and let the rest of the content scroll.

What do you think about this, in terms of pros and cons?

**[Update]**

With the new Top navigation bar, kudos to the design team, I think this question becomes relevant again. I'm aware of the busload of downvotes, but still.

The top navigation bar doesn't occupy much space and has **two** notification areas:

- Inbox
- Achievements

Having these **two** notifications visible at all times would be nice, IMO.

**[Update]**

I've just noticed that I haven't used the word "optional" in this discussion... My bad. In Excel, the Freeze function is controlled by the user. You can optionally Freeze part of the interface, and you can eliminate the Freeze at will.

Comment: There's a script that does this, [Stackoverflow.com Enhancer](http://stackapps.com/questions/2084/stackoverflow-com-enhancer-sticky-top-bars)

Comment: That script doesn't work on IE, why we need a script? why it is not part of SO? this absolutely common in many websites.

Comment: Because it's mostly obnoxious. The focus is on questions and answers. That bar just takes up space and gets in the way of seeing them.

Comment: Every application is focused on what is shown in the main UI area. This is a void argument. Then let's remove the browser toolbars as well... The existence of the Enhacer script demonstrates that many users prefer the app bar frozen.

Comment: @user Stack overflow is a *website*. It is not an application. It should behave like a website, and that means ***never*** grabbing part of my screen and pretending that it owns it.

Comment: You've asked the question in the right place, but I don't feel the feature has a lot of value. For one, it's fairly easy to navigate to the top of the page without manually scrolling (e.g. on my Mac it's just Cmd+UpArrow, and I'm sure on Windows it can be done in a similar way). Second, I have yet come across one of these "sticky" elements that hasn't been absolutely annoying. Can you point to one that works well?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Couldn't be easier on Windows: I just press Home. More for devil's advocate purposes than anything else, I will point out that the "action bar" on the new `/review` page (the one with the "accept," "close" and "not sure" buttons) is sticky. It doesn't come into play very often because mosts posts aren't that long. Or maybe it does, and I just can't tell because I orient my monitor vertically.

Comment: I'm sure this could be easily done with a userscript / user style sheet for those who really *want* it

Comment: @Pekka: [Indeed it can be](http://stackapps.com/questions/2043/a-way-to-keep-the-user-bar-on-the-top-of-the-site-stuck-there-stickybar)

Comment: @Pekka this wont need a script, it can easly done with css. just need to be that element's css; position:fixed and top:0

Comment: And also many useful answers (keyboard shortcuts) at [Toolbar with floating position](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114962/toolbar-with-floating-position).

Comment: The person asked is getting -65 and person replying getting +114? For Feedback. Chocolate is imp then wrapper or both imp for both?

Comment: Welcome to Meta StackOverflow :-) @hbdevror

Comment: I agree, this would be nice.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've up voted this.   I also agree the Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow toolbar should be fixed at the top of the screen.

Comment: I am puzzled as to why people are so upset/offended at a feature that could be made to be *optional*.  Simply default this option to be turned off (not fixed), and let those who wish to turn it on do so.  That way those that don't want it, don't have to worry about changing a thing.   As programmers we have the unique opportunity to make some great stuff, and here we are knocking other programmers for wanting to make the site more usable for some of the population? That doesn't sit right with me, especially since it could be optional.

Comment: @SlyRaskal The optional nature of this was only recently added

Comment: Personally, I prefer the [Scroll to Top Button](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scroll-to-top-button/chiikmhgllekggjhdfjhajkfdkcngplp) Chrome extension. It adds a floating button that jumps the page to the top (or bottom) with just a click, and works everywhere.

Comment: @RichardTingle, silly me, I thought people were aware of the optional nature of the 'freeze' function in Excel. Sigh.

Comment: @GUI I thought that was why you made that edit, to make it clear that this would be optional. Am I missing something

Comment: @RichardTingle, correct, that's why I made the edit.

Comment: Urgh! It's so distracting, and pointless. You just need to change your habits. Start using the shortcut key, or make one if needed. Or use the scroll to the right. The latest is to make it appear when you scroll a certain way down, and it always feels clunky and intrusive. I want to see content down the page, not content from up the page in content further down. Navigation should be up the top, where it is natural.

Comment: just my 2 cents ... https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/SETopBar

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I myself use the following home-brewed User stylesheet (in conjunction with [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/stylish/)). I don't need the whole bar to stick to the top, only the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™, for inbox messages.

```css
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain('stackoverflow.com'),
               domain('stackexchange.com'),
               domain('superuser.com'),
               domain('serverfault.com'),
               domain('stackapps.com'),
               domain('askubuntu.com'),
               domain('mathoverflow.com'),
               domain('answers.onstartups.com') {
  /* old StackExchange top bar, e.g. on stackexchange.com */
  #portalLink {
      position: fixed;
    /*left: 22px;/* Uncomment to stick to the left */
      background-image: -moz-element(#custom-header) !important;
      background-size: 1px !important;
      background-repeat: repeat !important;
      padding: 8px 6px 6px 16px !important;
      margin: -2px 0 0 -22px !important;
      border-radius: 5px;
  }
  /* Stick inbox to the left side of the page */
  .topbar .icon-inbox {
      position: fixed !important;
      left: 0;
  }
  .topbar .inbox-dialog {
      position: fixed !important;
      left: 0 !important;
  }
}
@-moz-document url-prefix('https://stackexchange.com/'),
               url-prefix('http://stackexchange.com/') {
    #portalLink {
        background-image: -moz-element(#topBar) !important;
    }
}
```

If you want to stick the whole top bar to the top, replace the two `.topbar { ... }` rules with:

```
body {
    padding-top: 34px; /* reserve height of .topbar */
}
.topbar {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

To eliminate the need for hard-coding colors, I'm painting the background using the [`-moz-element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element) CSS property.

Here's how it looks like with the default stylesheet (notice the StackExchange inbox at the upper-left corner):
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll try it out on my other machine when I get a chance.

Comment: Do you think you can update the script now that we have the new top bar, and maybe just make the top bar stick?

Comment: @LanceRoberts Added my current stylesheet to the answer.

Comment: @RobW, thanks, haven't got it to work yet, but I'll work on it more today.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work.  I'm pretty weak on CSS, but was wondering if this code that their currently using needs to be modded: .topbar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86);
    height: 34px;
    width: 100%;
}
.topbar .topbar-wrapper {
    height: 34px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 980px;
}  Maybe the `scroll` part, or the `position:relative` on the .topbar-wrapper?

Comment: @LanceRoberts If you want to freeze the top bar, use this style sheet: http://pastebin.com/ub2kd0sf. Otherwise, if you only want to fix the inbox icon, use the code as shown in my answer.

Comment: I just noticed that we need another `z-index : 2000;` (or similar) for the bar to be above e.g. the second code block in this answer (which has `1000`).

Comment: Also, [mathoverflow.SE] was missing. [Here's my version](https://gist.github.com/akerbos/8331073).

Comment: I have encountered another issue: "scrollers" like e.g. the one when you ask a question, slides behind the top bar. Since it seems to be moved by JS (`moveScroller()`) there is probably little hope to fix that in CSS, isn't there?

Comment: @Raphael It could be moved with CSS (e.g. with css transformations, `transform: translateY(34px);` ). But finding and dealing with all edge cases requires quite a lot of work. Since I'm only interested in the inbox button, I'll leave my answer like that, with the minimal implementation (without edge cases) of a floating top bar.

Comment: [Things changed](https://gist.github.com/akerbos/8331073). We need to fix `header.top-bar` now, and the extra padding on `body` has to go.

Answer (score 59):

Show of hands: How many people ***loathe*** headers and footers that follow you around as you scroll?

The header isn't even that useful when you're reading a long page, and you can always press <kbd>Home</kbd> to warp to the top.

Comment: mate its just got 33px height.

Comment: It would still bug me at 5px in height.

Comment: @barlasapaydin why do you think the height is the part that people find annoying?

Comment: okey, whatever, it was just a suggestion.

Comment: I __hate__ them. I use too many slightly buggy browsers where I can't switch. Floating toolbars are a very common rendering problem for me; please never do this to my favourite website!

Comment: `Home` is a one-way ticket; I need to get down to comment with my findings!

Comment: So *that* is what `Home` is for...

Comment: "Show of votes" more like. +1 though.

Comment: i'm the exact opposite. i hate not always having a *fixed* header on most sites

Answer (score 25):

(IMHO) I think it's not the best idea... It just adds noise/clutter when you don't need it whilst you've scrolled to view Question/Answer content. It's easy enough to get back to the top anyway.

As Michael Mrozek pointed out, there is an [add-on](https://stackapps.com/questions/2084/stackoverflow-com-enhancer-sticky-top-bars) that provides this functionality which after reviewing only confirms to me that I would not want such a feature... But at least it is an option for people who do want that — I can see why it would be useful, just that I'd want a clearer picture when scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea why this question was downvoted???

Comment: @GUI junkie, likely because people disagreed...voting is different on meta

Comment: how 20-30 pixels in height add more clutter? then a toolbar in all website add more clutter? toolbar are there to be accessed at any time by the user, whithough having to scroll.

Comment: @JaimeOlivares By taking away 20-30 pixels of page space that doesn't really change. The toolbar has useful things sure, but nothing that really changes why you are on a particular page...

Comment: That's exactly why the toolbar is there. It shows you information of the global context, not of the current page. If it doesn't belong to the current page, it should not scroll. This is UI Design 101.

Comment: Moreover, there is no point in having a notification control (incoming emails) when the notification area won't be always visible.

Comment: @JaimeOlivares It might have changed, but the notification bar does not change whilst viewing a page. You couldn't just leave it open and receive notifications...(this may have changed though)...

Comment: @davidsleeps: It changed :)

Answer (score 11):

I made a [userstyle](http://userstyles.org/styles/96849/se-top-bar-sticks-to-top) for the new top-bar to stick it to the top:

```css
@-moz-document regexp("https?://((?:(?!blog|chat|area51).)+\\.)?stackexchange\\.com/.*"), regexp("https?://(?:(?!blog|chat[^.]*).)*stackoverflow\\.com/.*"), regexp("https?://(?:(?!blog|chat).)*superuser\\.com/.*"), regexp("https?://(?:(?!blog|chat).)*serverfault\\.com/.*"), regexp("https?://(?:(?!blog|chat).)*mathoverflow\\.net/.*"), regexp("https?://(?:(?!blog|chat).)*stackapps\\.com/.*"), regexp("https?://(?:(?!blog|chat).)*askubuntu\\.com/.*") {
    body .topbar,
    body #topbar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    body > .page,
    body .container,
    div.wrapper > header {
        padding-top: 34px;
    }
    body .custom-header,
    body #custom-header,
    div#scroller,
    div.review-bar {
        top: 34px !important;
    }
    div#custom-header {
        margin-top: 34px;
    }
    .new-topbar .container {
        background-position: center 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! In particular, good to know that Sylish *does* deal with RegExps; searching the web led to mostly negative answers. Two minor enhancements: 1) You are missing some sites, see [Rob's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142217/156248). The sidebar on "Ask Question" moves behind the top bar. See [here](https://gist.github.com/akerbos/8331073) for a fix, if not a nice one.

Comment: And, of course, this wreaks havoc on site without the new top bar (SE blog, chat, main portal). But let's hope that all these will be ported, eventually.

Comment: @Raphael Thanks for the comments, I tried to include all sites that use the new top-bar now (not sure if I'm still missing some) and exclude chat/blog and SE portal. I'll edit the post with the updated style in a minute.

Comment: Aaaand another bug: popup notices like "Welcome back! You have been logged in." are hidden behind the top bar since it only has `z-index: 250;`. Of course, adding `div#overlay-header { z-index : 1001 !important; }` solves the issue.

Comment: @Raphael I noticed and added that a while ago as well.

Answer (score 9):

Although this feature isn't built in (and I understand why people dislike it) there's actually [a userscript that does this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2043/a-way-to-keep-the-user-bar-on-the-top-of-the-site-stuck-there-stickybar) that you can use instead. It's not 100% bulletproof, but in general it'll work. Actually, it turns out [there's a second one as well](https://stackapps.com/questions/2084/stackoverflow-com-enhancer-sticky-top-bars?lq=1).

Comment: lol i discover there is an userscripts for stack websites (: thanks.

Comment: interesting, i might want to find/write one that does this for the voting arrows

Answer (score 2):

As of February 2017 such feature is available on Stack Overflow, as announced [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update).

The top bar is sticky by default, and it can be turned off in the Edit Profile page.

As [confirmed by the project manager of the team](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7053530#7053530), the sticky top bar will be implemented network wide during the second half of 2018.

Answer (score -2):

A frozen top bar would be great.  It really sucks right now having to scroll back up every time you dive into a question.  I work a lot in Excel and any kind of heavy spreadsheet work usually involves freezing the top row (or leftmost column).

Some of the useful things in the top bar:

- I'm constantly getting notifications so I want the notification dropdown box visible always
- If I see a rep change I usually check out what has changed, so I need my username link visible for that
- Suggested Edit flags appear in that bar, and I always take care of those I can
- The 'review' button is in the bar and I check that a lot

**It would make the site more efficient and usable, thereby giving more time to process Q & A.**

Comment: I don't understand the 'I use it in Excel - a desktop application - so it should be available in everything else' stance you seem to be taking. Also, I don't see how it would be more 'efficient and usable'. If anything it would be *less* efficient and usable as anything happening in that toolbar would distract you from writing your answer. Real-world example: If I'm trying to read something that requires thought and mid-way through my reading someone comes and drops a big envelope on my desk, that would be distracting. But if they wait until I've finished reading to do so that's acceptable.

Comment: @JonW, I certainly didn't mean that everything in Excel should be available, this is just such an obviously useful feature that anyone who does a lot of Excel work will understand.  One of the most irritating things about use the SE sites is having to scroll back up to the top all the time.

Comment: Have you tried the “Home” key?

Comment: What is there in the top bar that's so important that it needs to be constantly visible no matter where you are on the page? It's just a bunch of links.

Comment: @Toomai, A) I'm constantly getting notifications so I want the notification dropdown box visible always, B) If I see a rep change I usually check out what has changed, so I need my username link visible for that, C) Suggested Edit flags appear in that bar, and I always take care of those I can, D) The 'review' button is in the bar and I check that a lot.  I'll edit all that into the answer.

Comment: I'm with @LanceRoberts on this, I'd like to see my status w/o scrolling.

Comment: Facebook users begone! This is not a social networking platform.