# StackExchange Notification Window - appear on new notification

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

When scrolling down page and reading posts, it'd be nice to see the StackExchange notifications so as to not scroll up to top to see if I have new messages -- similar to how some social sharing tools will move from the top of the article to the white space left of page content and scroll down with you.

I don't mean having the top navigation being sticky/frozen at the top. I mean move some key notifications to the empty white space outside of site content, if your window is wide enough.  Also not talking about extra scripts, browser add-ons, hitting the home button etc. I just mean simple, unobtrusive way to see notifications when you are reading other content and don't want to scroll away.

**UPDATE:** After implementing [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen/142217#142217) from a previous post and changing style to look like my mockup below, the result was a little annoying when the box was always there. *Amending this feature request to suggest that the StackExchange box would only appear on the left when you have a new notification, otherwise you don't see it. So if you get a new message while reading, it would fade-in and you could click to read it without having to scroll away from your content.*

[image: Notification Appears without need to scroll]

Comment: You mean to have the top bar stick to the top of the page when you scroll? I would like *that* idea.

Comment: Not a duplicate of top "should the top navigation be frozen" because I wasn't talking about top navigation... or freezing it. Similar concept, different approach. i.e. if your window is size of site content, you wouldn't see the notification window, so it wouldn't interfere with normal flow of site.

Comment: Post some mockup of what you mean, it will greatly help people to understand.

Comment: Added. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev [Did you look at this answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142217/155556)

Comment: Yes, and edited style to look like my mockup... and having notification window there was annoying :)

Comment: So what you mean is have something similar to the right menu [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)?

Comment: Similar, yes. It'd be a little more dynamic though (i.e. not visible when top menu is visible). Just updated Question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree, sorry. I sort of get what you mean and why, and I can see the benefits, but my workflow involves opening Stack Overflow fresh on so many tabs, so often, that I *don't need it* — and, as such, it wouldn't be worth the annoyance of this notification popping up at me wherever I go when I'm in the middle of writing a question or answer.