# What about a fixed top bar for better ease-of-access?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, top-bar

Recently I noticed the changes to the top bar. They are good but I had a suggestion, what about fixing the topbar at the top of the viewport for the user to simply access it regardless of on what position they are on the site ? I mean they don't need to scroll up every time to access the topbar.

[image: Fixed topbar]

I know this topic has been discussed earlier and the obvious answer was that use a grease-monkey script or something similar to it to make it fixed on your browser, this can be a good addition in order to make user interface better.

Thanks and hope to get some positive response :)

UPDATE: I respect your opinions and thus closing this topic.

Comment: I'd like this as it would allow me to be notified of any changes even if I'm not at the top of the page.

Comment: I don't like idea, as it is ugly and I don't want to look at it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should the top navigation be frozen?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen) Also, [Fixed menu or reputation bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/fixed-menu-or-reputation-bar?rq=1)

Comment: @mpapec changes always looks ugly at first but then you get used to it.

Comment: Here's the css to do it (I even got the shadow and the z-index): `.topbar{position: fixed;-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);z-index: 1003;}.container{margin-top: 34px}`

Comment: I have the top-bar fixed on my browser using a user agent file already. But all I was trying to do was suggesting a user interface addition. And @AshishNitinPatil, I know the question is similar but sorry none of the answers on that discussion answers me.

Comment: It was just a suggestion, but I think it's not going to work. Thanks anyway for taking time and responding.

Answer (score 4):

I run a userscript which optionally toggles the top bar to be fixed to the top. I honestly don't use it nearly as much as I thought I would.

It turns out that scrolling up to the top of the page is pretty easy. Also, the path I use to leave a page tends to be from a link in the current post, or back to the questions tab, which is not included in the top bar and requires a scroll anyway.

Overall, it is good in theory, but not in practice.

Comment: You're right, it's not a hard thing to scroll up, but think,  scrolling up each and every time to check for new notifications is not comfortable. Users will be able to see the notifications immediately if the top-bar is always in view.

Well, it can be good in practice too if used correctly. For example Facebook uses a fixed header already and it has a significant effect on the user interface.

Comment: @DeepakKamat - I feel like I visit the top of the page or navigate to a new page more often than I get new notifications. They **rarely** pile up.