# Please abort the fixed/hovering/sticky review result panel

Tags: feature-request, design, suggested-edits

I just noticed [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48870) that the review result panel, showing the review item status is fixed and sticking always on top:

> [image]

I don't like sticky contents. They hinder my reading and just interfere. If I want to know the status, I just scroll up and take a look.

Previous attempts to ask for a fixed/sticky top bar has always been declined, e.g. [What about a fixed top bar for better ease-of-access?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210241/what-about-a-fixed-top-bar-for-better-ease-of-access) so the team itself also appears to share the dislike for sticky contents, hence not sure what happened here.

So, can we please have that panel put back in place and not follow us around?

Comment: You are so going to hate the new header design...

Comment: @Oded sticky header?? Sigh... never imagined the team will go against the will of majority of the users. Wait, only for SO, right? So I don't really care. :-)

Comment: Well, SO only *for now*... We can't really maintain two different headers for a long time.

Comment: Oh no..... but why nothing about that in MSE then? That's really unfair toward those who aren't active on MSO thus can't express their opinions.

Comment: Mostly due to it being still in development and going through A/B testing. I don't expect this to roll into any other site for a good while yet.

Comment: Good! Hopefully it will take at least the same time it's taking to "new nav" to be done. ;-)