# The review sticky panel should actually be sticky

Tags: bug, review, design

Currently, the sticky review result panel is causing the page to jump up and down as I scroll. It's irritating. This is because JavaScript is changing it from `position: static;` to `position: fixed;`. It should just have `position: sticky;`.

Exacerbating this issue is that the close description is now displayed even if you click the [(less)](//) link, making the bar take up a considerable amount of the screen – and so rendering areas of the page literally impossible to bring into view unless I make my browser window massive. This is a usability concern.

I would like to be able to review without deleting elements from the DOM.

Comment: What exactly is this sticky panel? I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @Stormblessed https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290301/308065