# Not able to see the notification when I'm at the bottom of the question section

Tags: support, notifications

I'm new to stack overflow meta.The one issue which I constantly find on stack overflow is I'm not able to see the notification at the bottom of the page **particularly when I'm scrolling down in questions section**.So, Is there any setting/functionality for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should the top navigation be frozen (optional)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen-optional)

Comment: In the duplicate question see [the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142217/187824).

Comment: I'm not talking about the frozen notification bar ,but something like a toast message at the bottom.

Comment: And what is a toast message, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any setting/preference for getting [a toast message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220669/not-able-to-see-the-notification-when-im-at-the-bottom-of-the-question-section?noredirect=1#comment715554_220669) when you are not at the top. Only available option to do *something like this* is make your notification bar frozen using [this external script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142217/187824)*.

<sup>* And this is not supported officially by SE team.</sup>