# Stack Exchange websites should have a fixed topbar so that it scrolls with the page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, top-bar

The entire topbar should be fixed so that it scrolls down with the page.

Why is this not a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen-optional): I am asking we should have this functionality, I'm not looking for workarounds. This is both, a discussion and a feature-request.

People complain that it can be noisy. I disagree. For example, check this image. I just added two styles (`position: fixed` and `width: 100%`) and it doesn't look any noisy, but better. It's around 35px and has just six icons: not much noise, and just think what the fixed search bar can do! It can be really helpful.

[image: a fixed AskUbuntu topbar]

- When scrolling down, you can "warp back" by pressing the <kbd>Home</kbd> button, but there's a reason why a lot of websites use this functionality.
- It will help when reading long texts, especially when you're being active on multiple SE websites and/or questions.
- It'll notify you of comments, answers, rep changes, etc. in real time when you're focussing on multiple SE websites and/or questions. As of now, you have to finish one page and then scroll all up to find any comments or answers on other questions.

*We might skip this for mobile versions and smartphone apps of StackExchange.*

Comment: I absolutely *hate* those things. With a passion.

Answer (score 3):

if you want it so shall you have it

just do a userscript that includes this one line

```
.topbar { position: fixed; }
```