# Which question/answer had the most upvotes and downvotes combined?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes

Which question or answer in all of Stack Exchange had the most upvotes and downvotes combined? Under the criteria the following criteria: Upvote percentage must be between 40% and 60% (inclusive).

Rarely do you see questions or answers with an upvote percentage between that range. It's either al(most) all upvoted or all downvoted.

Comment: Including or excluding meta sites? Because if it including, uh. This actually is pretty common.

Comment: Would love to see it on both meta and regular sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/743974/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site) does exactly that. If you run it, you will see a list of posts that have more than half the amount of downvotes as they have upvotes (which means that they have between 33% and 67% upvotes). The posts are ordered by the amount of upvotes.

For example, from this query, I was able to find that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18018493/4284627) is the most controversial post on Stack Overflow (it has 406 upvotes and 242 downvotes for those that don't have 1k reputation on Stack Overflow) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114020/349538) is the most controversial post on Meta Stack Exchange (it has 234 upvotes ans 122 downvotes for those who don't have 1k reputation here). If you're looking for posts that have a number of upvotes and a number of downvotes that are very close to each other, using the query, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641305/4284627) on Stack Overflow (139 upvotes and 120 downvotes) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101385/349538) on Meta Stack Exchange (82 upvotes and 60 downvotes).

Comment: Good find! I was surprised this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706028/creating-a-elisp-function-to-convert-url-to-html-link) wasn't included. +32/-33

Answer (score 3):

This is the network wide [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/747018) that does what you ask for.

When run today these are top post with [Introducing the Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story) being the "winner" (based on ordering on total votes):

[image]

Here is the actual SQL query:

```sql
-- start create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO
-- create url based on dbname
create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @p1 nvarchar(250) = parsename(@dbname,1)
      declare @p2 nvarchar(250) = parsename(@dbname,2)
      declare @p3 nvarchar(250) = parsename(@dbname,3)
      set @res = 
        (case  @dbname 
         when 'StackExchange.Meta' then 'Meta.StackExchange'
         when 'StackOverflow.Meta' then 'Meta.StackOverflow'
         when 'StackExchange.Audio' then 'avp.StackExchange'
         when 'StackExchange.Audio.Meta' then 'Avp.Meta.StackExchange'
         when 'StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta' then 'meta.Mathoverflow.net'
         when 'StackExchange.Mathoverflow' then 'Mathoverflow.net'
      else (case when @p1 = 'Meta' then @p2 else @p1 end) + 
           (case when @p2 is null then '' else '.' end) +
           (case when @p1 = 'Meta' then @p1 else isnull(@p2,'') end) +
           (case when @p3 is null then '' else '.' end) +
           isnull(@p3,'')     
      end) + '.com'
   end;
GO

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE
                        -- and [name] not like 'StackOverflow'

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_posts ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , title nvarchar(250)
                            , postid int
                            , upvotes int
                            , downvotes int);
                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'
    use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
    declare @url nvarchar(250)
    exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
    insert into #all_posts 
    select -- top 10
      @url
     , ''tbd''
     , v.postid
     , sum(case when v.votetypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) 
     , sum(case when v.votetypeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) 
     from-- posts p
     -- inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id) and q.posttypeid = 1
     -- inner join 
     votes v -- on v.postid = p.id
     where v.votetypeid in (2,3)
     -- and p.posttypeid in (1,2) 
     group by -- q.title,
             v.postid
     having (cast(sum(case when v.votetypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as decimal) /
            (sum(case when v.votetypeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) 
            + sum(case when v.votetypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end)))
     between 0.4 and 0.6
     order by sum(case when v.votetypeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) 
            + sum(case when v.votetypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) desc
     '
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select replace(
       replace(
       replace(site,
         '.StackExchange.com',''),
         '.com',''),
         '.net','') as [site]
     , 'http://' 
     + site 
     + '/q/'
     + cast(postid as nvarchar)
     + '| Post Id: '
     + cast(postid as nvarchar) as post
     , upvotes
     , downvotes
from #all_posts
order by  upvotes + downvotes desc

drop table #all_posts

drop procedure #siteurl
```

Due to the resource hungry nature of the join needed to get the post title I could only make this work by just querying the votes table for each site. Due to that I can only offer the ID of the post for a specific site. Just click the link to find the actual post.

The query includes all main sites and site meta's.