# Toolbar with floating position

Tags: feature-request, toolbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An optional navigation bar floating at the top](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62082/an-optional-navigation-bar-floating-at-the-top)
>   [Should the top navigation be frozen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen)

It would be more comfortable to have a floating toolbar like current FB toolbar. It's easy to access anytime, doesn't matter how long did you scrolled the page.

Comment: Arr...at least it's a duplicate of the "make it float" part...let me see if I find a better one.

Comment: Well, I could swear this was asked and declined before! But I can't find it...

Comment: but what's the reason of declining?

Comment: You're not asking to fix the position of the existing top bar, are you? (If so, then see [Should the top navigation be frozen?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen))

Comment: @Arjan, yes it's the same idea that I meant.

Answer (score 4):

Before you even *discuss* whether something should be a toolbar, or whatever - first you need to know **what you want to put there**. I'm very unclear what features/buttons would be always relevant and pertinent to where-ever you scrolled, that don't already exist by the item they serve.

You might also be interested in the [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102769/keyboard-shortcuts-phase-one), which may provide much of what you are after. Any use?

Personally, my view is that floating toolbars only apply in a very limited number of scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably down to personal preference, but I find floating fixed-position toolbars rather intrusive and reduces the usable real-estate in my browser.

I remove as many toolbars as I can from the browser (bookmarks, addons, etc...) and it would irk me if a website then forces one on me.

In the rare occasion that I need to access the top links while I'm deep in a page, I'd much rather have a shortcut key that scrolls me to the top of the page. For now, I'm doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> which reloads the page (thus grabbing new notifications) and put me back where I started.

As pointed out by Bobby in the comments, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> scolls to the top of the page which is also useful since it doesn't require reloading the page and will still work if the URL navigates you to mid-page.

---

p.s. the [initial GM script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/so-site-bar-minimalistic) that predates the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ had `position:fixed`, but there was some objection to that positioning. IMHO, you'd be hard pressed to convince the dev/design team to make the toolbar be displayed as such.

Comment: yes, I can understand you, some time ago I had a netbook with a small screen. so maybe the toolbar could be floating depending on user preferences...

Comment: `Ctrl + Home` for example...yeah, I know, not the most convenient one.

Comment: but on small keyboards there is no "Home" button

Comment: @Bobby Aha... that's easier than Ctrl+L,Enter combo I use. Works a little different, but just as useful.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about that Combo-possibility.

Comment: I don't know if this has a Windows equivalent, but Command-Up (the up-arrow) scrolls to the top in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on a Mac, @haynar. (On Windows plain Home and End seem to be the documented shortcuts for Firefox.)