# Navigate between answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface

I came across [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time-experimental-challenge) question, and I must admit I've never seen such a long page with so many long answers.

The problem is easily navigating between the answers.

Sometimes I don't have time to read everything at once, and it becomes rather annoying to endlessly scroll to pick up on where I left off.

I think it would be helpful to have a box (in the white space on the left) with links to different answers to hop down to them. Of course this would only be activated when the page becomes a certain length and/or if there are X amount of answers.

Here is an idea (excuse my horrible design skills):

[image: quick-links-V2]

Comment: You can add your mockup and idea as answer on the dupe.

Comment: You should also see [waffle's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62072/230506). It was 5 years ago, so maybe comment to Waffles, but to be fair I think the question you have found is pretty rare. Adding a new navigation just for rare scenarios is not really worth the dev time IMO.

Comment: @James yes I think the question I came upon is quite rare. However, there are quite a lot of questions that have long answers and/or many answers in general. I agree it might not be worth the dev's time, still useful for those rare scenarios.

Comment: @Grimbode There's no harm in asking :) We don't really know how much dev time this would take. "Probs" enough to make it not worthwhile, but if it's a quick job, they might implement it and only show nav when answer count is more than X (but, I doubt it, there are more *juicy* feature requests in the waiting :) )

Comment: A user script implementing this idea is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259770).

Comment: @James reminds me of the sticky vote buttons we had a while ago. And we all know how it ended... too many users just don't like too much cheese to be moved around. ;)